# Suggest a Normalization technique in MySql

Tags: mysql

following is my table structure

TABLE 1:

```
CREATE TABLE page_visits
(
  domain varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  campaign_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
  subscriber_id BIGINT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Sample rows of above table.

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| domain    | subscriber_id    | campaign_id      |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| abcdef    | 5834234569635200 | 5814789314123456 |
| abcdef    | 5834979786543520 | 5814789314123456 |
| abcdef    | 1238003995770880 | 5814789314123456 |
| abcdef    | 4567900658540544 | 5814789314123456 |
| abcdef    | 8765906092156928 | 5814789314123456 |
+--------+------------------+---------------------+
```

We have 100 million rows (approx) and the size is 100 GB (approx). I want to normalize this table. Instead of having "varchar" datatype for domain , I want to use domain_id as medium int in above table. Because domain name is repeating lot of times in this table.

I will keep domains in separate table like the following and domain name will be unique in following table.

TABLE 2:

```
CREATE TABLE domains
(
  domain_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  domain_name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Problem : For every read and write request for Table 1 , I need to call table 2 to get domain_id from domain name because I'm not storing domain_id in app. Anyway to optimize this to reduce the size ??

Comment: Optimize in what way? Make queries faster or reduce query count?

Comment: Do domains change? If not, then there's little point substituting one number for another. EVERY table should have a PRIMARY KEY, but that key does not need to be a surrogate.

Comment: @Strawberry domain name doesn't change

Comment: In which case substituting an integer for a string will have very little performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

table page_vits create statement :

```
CREATE TABLE `page_visits` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscriber_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `domain_id_idx` (`domain_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `domain_id` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `domains` (`domain_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now domain_id references to your domain table.

table domain create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
  `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=46 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

ER diagram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal problem where you trade off between performance and normalization.
In your case specifically, you can do the following:

1. Keeping the table structure normalized bodes well for a RDBMS type of database. Also, there is an added performance advantage of using *integer* datatypes (in your `where` clause) over *string* datatypes to perform any of your select queries, as they require lesser CPU time.
2. Considering you create `domains` table to adhere to normalization, partition your `page_visits` table based on an appropriate condition, so that the selects you perform are always fetching data from a single partition.
   Read about [MySQL partitioning limitations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html).
3. Index the `domain_id` column in the `page_visits` table to fetch rows faster. [This will of course be tricky based on your different problem statements, and might have to be altered if required].